# Adding a space before 3rd character from end of string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular JS and I am doing the validation for UK postal code. Issue is there is a specific requirement that there should be an space in the the UK postal code which can be identified only by counting character from last.As there should be a space before third last character It should look like:

> A12 3AD
>   A123 3AD
>   A2 2AD

For doing that I have 2 major issues:

1. How to manipulate input value to induce space.
2. How to actually change the string to add space

I am new to `javascript/angular` can someone tell me how to do that?

PS: I am not using jQuery in project.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method and replace last 3 characters with leading space or assert the position using [positive look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and replace with a white space.

```
string = string.replace(/.{3}$/,' $&');
// or using positive look ahead assertion
string = string.replace(/(?=.{3}$)/,' ');
```

```js
console.log(
  'A123A123'.replace(/.{3}$/, ' $&'), '\n',
  'A13A123'.replace(/.{3}$/, ' $&'), '\n',
  'A1A123'.replace(/.{3}$/, ' $&'), '\n',
  'AA123'.replace(/.{3}$/, ' $&'), '\n',
  'A123'.replace(/.{3}$/, ' $&'), '\n',
  'A123'.replace(/(?=.{3}$)/, ' ')
)
```

---

Or you can use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method with [positive look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regex.

```
string = string.split(/(?=.{3}$)/).join(' ');
```

```js
console.log(
  'A123A123'.split(/(?=.{3}$)/).join(' ')
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **regex** function to perform your action.

```
string = string.replace(/.{3}$/,' $&');
```

it specifies that : from last, space will be given to before 3rd last value

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing text of input, without providing notice of what required input is; provide notice to user what the requirement is for the field using `title`, `placeholder`, `required` attributes and `:invalid` pseudo class at `css`, with `pattern` attribute set to `RegExp` `^[A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}\s[A-Za-z0-9]{3}$`.

```css
input[type="text"] {
  width: 200px;
}

input:invalid {
  color:red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" 
       title="Input three alphanumeric characters, a space, followed by three alphanumeric characters. All other input is invalid."
       placeholder="Input valid UK postal code."
       pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}\s[A-Za-z0-9]{3}$"
       required/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be useful

Use `splice` method to break the string in two pieces. `string.length-3` will give the last three characters where as `string.slice(0, string.length-3)` will return the first `n-3` characters starting from beginning of the string.Use `array.join` method to join the pieces

```
function insertSpace(string){
var output = [string.slice(0, string.length-3),' ', string.slice(string.length-3)].join('');
return output
}
console.log(insertSpace('A1233AD'))
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5tf0zh55/3/)

Answer (score -1):

You can also use substring function:

str.substring(0, str.length - 3) + " " + str.substring(str.length, str.length - 3)